# Weld TransactionServices, how does one register this?

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, cdi, jta, jboss-weld

I'm trying junit test with CDI/Weld and JEEUnit. I get this message on startup:

```
189 [main] INFO org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap - WELD-000101 Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
```

Later on, the Entitymanager fails when I call `em.flush()` because they expect a transaction to be active. Is there a lightweight transaction implementation I can use for JUnit testing?

EDIT:

I ended up using GuiceRunner. This is so brilliantly simple...
http://fabiostrozzi.eu/2011/03/27/junit-tests-easy-guice/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [openEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/) in unit-tests, this should work as expected.

***But***: As soon as you need a transaction (aka "platform service") in a test, I would start to call it *integration testing* - in this case I recommend to use  [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) for light-weight on-container testing. You will be able to test against *your own infrastructure*, and  use an real-world setup for eg. transactions.

**Update**: I overlooked that you are using JEEUnit already. That makes my answer pretty obsolete...

Comment: I couldn't agree more... but I don't _want_ a transaction though. It's being forced on me by weld. If I manually create entity manager, I can set it to RESOURCE_LOCAL and everything is peachy. However, then I lose dependency injection for my loggers and entity managers :(

Comment: ... shouldn't those be mockable or replaceable with `@Alternative` in a unit-test?

Comment: I don't think Mocking an EntityManager is a good idea. Given that the @Query is in the code, they need to be tested.

Answer (score 2):

To get past the INFO message, you need to have the jta api on your classpath, but then you'll have a problem with actually not having a real transaction live later on.

Comment: Thanks, i'll at least give it a try and see what happens.